# Increase Bidding Rate On Assests In Opensea-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, web3js, opensea

everyone so I have been working on a Bidding Bot to make Offers on Assests of a Collection on Opensea.io. The Bot works fine, but there is one thing that I would want to improve, which is the speed, currently my Bot makes 20 - 25 Offers in a minute. I have seen people claiming that there Bots can make more then 100 offers per minute. My question is how do I improve the speed of my Bot. Is there any way to do this? If so can anyone explain to me how? your help would make my day. Thanks. Peace!

Comment: you need to share your code so we can help you! Which node provider are you using?

Comment: @MusayyabNaveed I am using infura